# What is the proper translation of "Victoriarum Romae" (two genitives in a row)?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, genitive

I was given the exercise to translate *Victoriarum Romae* into English.
It's not a part of some bigger text: that's all I was given. I don't feel confident about my translation, "Of the victories of Rome".

Am I right in saying that this is two genitives in a row? Is that possible? It's the first time I have seen this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this kind of thing is possible.
There is no limit to how many genitives you can chain.
If you want to describe the properties "of the food of a dog of a man of a city of an empire", you can translate it as *cibi canis viri urbis imperii*.
Of course this gets silly at some point, but grammar does not limit it.

"Of the victories of Rome" is an excellent translation of *victoriarum Romae*.
But broader context will determine what the best translation is.
If *Romae* is singular dative or plural nominative instead, then you need to translate it correspondingly.

Latin tends to use adjectives for things like this, so I would translate "of the victories of Rome" from English to Latin as *victoriarum Romanarum* ("of the Roman victories").
But the genitive is grammatical as well.

Comment: There was a popular book called *De Rerum Naturae*...

Comment: @TimLymington I believe it was *De rerum natura*. The preposition *de* forces *natura* into ablative.